# How to plot specific points on ROC curve

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

I'm using [pROC package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/index.html) to plot receiver operating curves using the function:

```
plot(roc(true, predictor))
```

I also want to highlight points on the curve corresponding to specific p-values. Let's say I know which predictor values correspond to my specific p-values. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you paste a small, self contained example which we could extend?

Comment: "Let's say I know which predictor values correspond to my specific pvalues" This is wrong. The p-value reports on the significance of the whole ROC curve, not just a single point.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean predictor values corresponding to specific thresholds, not p-values. In this case with pROC you should use the `print.thres` argument. For instance if you want to highlight the threshold `2.2` on your predictor, you can write:

```
my.threshold <- 2.2
plot(roc(true, predictor), print.thres = my.threshold)
```

See `?plot.roc` for more options.